# Disable Register Button, When user Logs in

Tags: android, authentication, android-button

I have an android app that has a Login Button, which logs in once validated information with that in the SQLite database, I also have another button that is for Register.

How can I make it so when the user Login is successful the register button is disabled and only becomes clickable when the app is closed and restarted.

Below is the code for my two buttons.

```
public void onClickButton(View v) {

    // Login Button
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin) {
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpassword);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);
        if (pass.equals(password)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            // Show Toast Message
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username/ Password is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }
    }

    // Create account Button
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignup) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

} // Ends onClickButtonenter code here
```

If you could give  suggestions or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: why you want that register button to be disable.because when you login it goes to next screen na..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
public void onClickButton(View v) {

    // Login Button
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin) {
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpassword);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);
        if (pass.equals(password)) {
        register_button.setEnabled(False)
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
        register_button.setEnabled(True)
            // Show Toast Message
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username/ Password is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }


    }

    // Create account Button
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignup) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the buttons visibility to GONE, so it will be completely removed or to INVISIBLE after you logged in.

```
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you wont save any state after restarting the app the button will be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate the view in your Activity and you create your `Button` objects. You could test for the successful login and then use

```
if (someCheckForASuccessfulLogin){
    theRegisterButton.setEnabled(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make one extra field in database**

Set one more field in database for checking user is already registered or not. If user register once set this field's value as "false".

**2. Check field value by getting it from database**

Now at login time first check this field value whether it's "true" or "false".
If value is false then write this line.
yourButtonName.setClickable(false);

if value is "true" then write yourButtonName.setClickable(true);

This will work definitely.